# Markowitz Minimum Variance Line - maximise return with a given variance?

Tags: mathematical-economics, portfolio-theory

There are many example online of how to use Lagrange multipliers to solve Markowitz's minimum variance problem (namely  find the weightings for the portfolio which minimises variance for a given return with constraints on the calculated return of said portfolio and the sum of weighting of all assets within the portfolio to 1). However I can't find an example of how to go the other way, find the weighting of the portfolio which maximises return for a given variance. I know they'd both fall on the efficient frontier..

Can anyone help?